# a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘:’ token

Tags: c++, unordered-map

While trying to write the below piece of code to iterate over an unordered_map I am struggling with the below error. Not getting much sense of that error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace std::tr1;

    unsigned char *expr = (unsigned char *)bufin;
    unordered_map <char, int> freq_map;
    while(expr != '\0')
    {
        char ch = *expr;
        freq_map[ch]++;
        expr++;
    }
    
    expr = (unsigned char *)bufin;
    for(auto & it: freq_map)
    {
        std::cout<<it.first<<"\t"<<it.second);
    }
```

The error:

```
 a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘:’ token
```

Comment: Are you compiling it as C++98 code? Why do you need to pull `unordered_map` from `tr1`?

Comment: Is the code you show truly a proper [mre]? Please create a proper [mre], and then copy-paste the full and complete build-log from that example. And add comments in the code where you get the error.

Comment: I think you forgot to declare main function or some other function in which you should put your code because your code is literally in global namepsace.

Comment: `tr1` is something from the dinosaurs era.

Comment: you need to read the whole complete errror message including the line number, the offending code, and the possible hints that come with it.

Comment: Did you use the correct flag to use the correct standard that support such code?

Comment: Also, considering the `tr1` stuff, what compiler are you using? And what version of it?

Comment: A compiler that actually *needs* `tr1` will not understand the `:` in a for-statement. You are mixing language generations **wildly**.

Comment: Aside from the problems alluded to above, are you trying to create a 8bit histogram of some kind ? (You're also mixing signed and unsigned chars, btw).
An `unsorted_map` is probably not the best type of container for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a pre C++11 compiler, you can't use [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) and must instead use iterators.

```cpp
// helper type definition to not have to repeat typing
// `unordered_map<char, int>` a lot:
typedef unordered_map<char, int> maptype;

// don't cast to `unsigned char*` when you need a `char*`:
char* expr = (char*)bufin;  // if `bufin` is already a `char*`, don't cast at all

maptype freq_map; // using the helper type definition

while (*expr != '\0') {  // dereference expr
    char ch = *expr;
    freq_map[ch]++;
    expr++;
    // or:      ++freq_map[*expr++];
}

// Your loop, using an iterator instead. Again using the helper typedef
for (maptype::iterator it = freq_map.begin(); it != freq_map.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << '\n';
}
```